# Angular 10 no longer adding headers to request via interceptor

Tags: angular

I've got a bit of code which has worked flawless for me for the last 5 or so angular versions.

Once upgrading to Angular 10 its no longer setting the bearer token on the header. I don't see anything in the upgrade notes about modifications to the HTTP client or how this would work.

Is there something slightly wrong with my code now anyone has had to deal with?

```js
  private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    await this.angularFireAuth.user.subscribe((user) => {
      user.getIdToken().then(
        (token) =>
          (request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            },
          }))
      );
    });

    return next.handle(request).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: I believe this may be related to `angularFireAuth`,are you tried to set static token just for sake of testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the problem is `angularFireAuth`. As you mentioned, when replacing the token with a known hard coded value I get the same problem. The token is known to work correctly (via postman) and I can also log it out successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manged to get things working again. Something must have been off with the flow, making use of a pipe + mergeMap I get the expected behavior

```js
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.angularFireAuth.idToken.pipe(
      mergeMap((token) => {
        return next.handle(
          request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            },
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```